# Updating app in iTunes, but want data to be ported over to new version of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app in the iTunes that uses Core Data. I am about to release a new app that has some  core data changes. My questions is:

How to update my app in the store and have the old apps CD data get copied or moved over to the new apps CD?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at this article from apple.com

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmUnderstandingVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH2-SW1

Essentially you need to force Core Data to recognize that the different versions of your models are different, you could set an entity modifier for the entity in the new version's model to change the version hash Core Data creates.

Here's info about the versionHashModifier:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPropertyDescription/versionHashModifier